# Date pipe : LOCALE_ID does not affect the timezone?

Tags: angular, date-pipe

In my app I sometimes display date and time like :

```
{{ object.dateStart | date:'shortDate' }} : {{ object.dateStart | date:'HH:mm' }}
```

In my app.module I do have :

```
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
...
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'th' },
```

The date is indeed displayed in good format (dd/mm/aaaa) but the timezone is not applied : If I navigate on my website with a computer in an english timezone, time will be displayed with english timezone, but I want it to be always displayed with the LOCALE_ID timezone (french in my case).
I could use :

```
{{ object.dateStart | date:'HH:mm':'UTC +2' }}
```

But then I have to specify timezone everywhere I need to display time. LOCALE_ID is not supposed to set the timezone? Is that a normal behaviour?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locale will only affect representation format and not timezone.

You can refer to this site what Locale actually changes in general which you can observe in your angular code.

http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/fr/index.html

Comment: Ah yes actually now that I think about it, it couldn't work anyway cause some countries have different timezone such as Russia ^^ Dumb me :) Thx!